# Can I connect black iron pipe directly to a gas cooktop?

Tags: plumbing, code-compliance, natural-gas, connectors, cooktops

I am moving into a new home. The kitchen has a separate gas cooktop and gas wall oven. Both were supplied by a half inch black iron pipe terminating at a valve in the bottom of one cabinet. From there, two flare fittings connected to a tee allowed for flexible gas connectors to run to each appliance. Each gas connector ran through several cabinets before reaching the appliance.

I added runs of black iron pipe so that they each terminate in the same cabinet/cavity as the appliance.

Underneath the gas cooktop is just a standard cabinet, where things like pots and pans could be stored. It also has two drawers which close almost to the very back of the cabinet. One drawer actually has a piece cut out of it to avoid hitting the regulator valve. I have two small children and I'm worried about the flexible gas line getting bumped by pots and pans in that cabinet. I am also unsure if this is even up to code (I'm in New York State) to have the flexible gas connector exposed inside of a usable cabinet space like this.

I would like to hard pipe all the way up to the appliance. The cooktop has a regulator valve underneath it with 1/2" female threading so my plan would be to add some fittings and pipe until I get to the other end of pipe terminating in the cabinet, then connect the two with a union. I see the utility in using a flexible gas connector for something like a combined range/oven or a gas dryer where it needs to be pulled away from the wall in order to connect/disconnect. In my situation however, I can open up the cabinet and have direct access to the connection and valve. Practically speaking, I don't see the need for the flexible connector aside from the fact that it would be quicker and easier to install.

To summarize, my questions are:

1. Is it legal in NYS to have a flexible gas connector exposed inside a used/ working cabinet space?
2. Can I legally forgo use of a flexible gas connector and use black iron pipe to connect directly to the appliance?

Comment: I didn't see anything in the 2020 fuel gas code of New York state referenced by Greg Hill in the selected answer, specifying individual shut off for each appliance. This is just a range and a wall oven, and they are very close, so both meet the requirement of being within 6 ft of the shut off valve. The valve is also in an obvious and easy to reach location. I really don't have a practical reason to add another shut off. If I am doing work on one, I'm not about to be cooking with the other at the same time. If you have any other reason to have two shut offs, I am interested to know!

Comment: I mean, you could use the flex connector and simply build a chase for it inside the cabinet...

Comment: "4.11 #1 explicitly states that **"rigid metallic pipe and fittings" are an approved means to connect an appliance.** I know you stated this but just wanted to" get it closer to the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [2020 Fuel Gas Code of New York State](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/NYSFGC2020P1/chapter-4-gas-piping-installations) available online. At first glance it appears similar to the International Fuel Gas Code.

Section 409.5.1 requires that a shutoff valve shall be in the same room as the appliance and within 6 feet of the appliance.

Section 411.1 on connecting appliances requires that "Listed and labeled appliance connectors" must be entirely in the same room as the appliance, and must be installed in accordance with the manufacturer's instructions.

Section 411.1.2 requires that appliance connectors shall be protected against physical damage. I guess there's room for interpretation here -- can small children armed with pots and pans damage an appliance connector? Is there something you could build with wood, sheet metal, or other materials to provide appropriate protection?

Section 411.1.3 addresses installation of appliance fuel connectors. Maximum length is 6 feet and only one shall be used for each appliance. They "shall not be concealed within, or extended through, walls, floors, partitions, ceilings or appliance housings."

I don't see that appliance connectors crossing through cabinets is prohibited. It sounds like you've already corrected the (likely) chaining of multiple appliance connectors together and eliminated the question about whether connectors may pass through cabinets.

I'm not certain whether there's anything *wrong* with having one shutoff valve serve two appliances -- but the more valves the merrier. Especially if the shutoff is further than 6 feet, or if it would be difficult for a person unfamiliar with the kitchen to find in case of emergency, feel free to add an additional shutoff valve nearer to each appliance. There should be no need to remove the existing one at the tee.

Hard piping all the way to the appliance is certainly allowed. Make sure that the piping is supported so that its weight is not exerting forces on the appliance, that the union is in an accessible place, that the shutoff valve is upstream of the union, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response. The digital code reference is very helpful. 411.1.3.3 - exception number 4 states that a cabinet used as a housing for the appliance is an exception to the rule of disallowing the connector to pass through a wall, partition, etc. In my case, the connector passed through multiple small cabinets, so I think technically it would not have been allowed.

Comment: 4.11 #1 explicitly states that "rigid metallic pipe and fittings" are an approved means to connect an appliance. I know you stated this but just wanted to add the code reference in.

Comment: For the record, my small children are absolutely capable and likely to destroy that flexible gas connector if armed with pots and pans. I am relieved that I can hard pipe this so I can use the cabinet and not need to screw it shut!